# How to generate an openapi client which uses only one of the available securitySchemes?

Tags: openapi, api-key, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI3 yaml file like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Test
  description: test
  version: 3.3.0
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      ...
      security:
        - ApiKeyAuth: []
        - ApiKeyAuthQuery: []
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: token
    ApiKeyAuthQuery:
      type: apiKey
      in: query
      name: token
```

which allows me to put the token apikey in *either* the header *or* the query. This works ok.

But now I want to generate a `typescript-fetch` client from this yaml, and I want to put the token only in the header.

Is there a way to tell the generator to prefer one of the apikey locations? Can I override the yaml definition "on the fly" only for the client?

Currently the generated clients are inserting the token in *both* query and header at the same time. I briefly checked also other client generators, and they seem to have the same problem.